# How can I make my bombs either fall faster or spawn faster the longer the game lasts?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nstimer, skaction

How can I make my bombs either fall faster or spawn faster the longer the game lasts? I am trying to make my game harder the longer you stay alive. I would like it to get harder every 10 bombs. I have been researching this for days and have tried multiple answers to similar questions. I believe the way I had to make my bombs is what is making it harder for me to do this. Thanks in advance!

```
var bombSpawnSpeed : NSTimeInterval = 0.40
var bombCounter : Int = 0
```

this is in my update func. My understanding is this is just the regular update func of the whole scene.

```
  override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

  if bombCounter >= 10 {
        if bombSpawnSpeed > 0.15 {
            bombSpawnSpeed -= 0.05
            bombCounter = 0

        }
        else {
            bombSpawnSpeed = 0.1

        }

    }
```

Here are the bombs

```
func enemies() {

    let bomb1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "AtomicBomb")
    let bomb2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "EMP")
    let bomb3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BioBomb")
    let bomb4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ChemBomb")

    let enemy = [bomb1, bomb2, bomb3, bomb4]


    // Enemy Physics
    for bomb in enemy {
        bomb1.size = CGSize(width: 55, height: 55)
        bomb2.size = CGSize(width: 55, height: 70)
        bomb3.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        bomb4.size = CGSize(width: 45, height: 70)


        bomb.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bomb.size.width / 4)
        bomb.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy
        bomb.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.missile | PhysicsCategory.airDefense
        bomb.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.missile | PhysicsCategory.airDefense
        bomb.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false 
        bomb.runAction(SKAction.speedBy(10, duration: 30))
        bomb.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        bomb1.name = "enemy1"
        bomb2.name = "enemy2"
        bomb3.name = "enemy3"
        bomb4.name = "enemy4"

        print("bomb")

    }

    let deployAtRandomPosition = arc4random() % 4

    switch deployAtRandomPosition {
    case 0:
        bomb1.position.y = frame.size.height

        let PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))

        bomb1.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

        self.addChild(bomb1)

        break

    case 1:
        bomb2.position.y = frame.size.height

        let PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))

        bomb2.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

        self.addChild(bomb2)

        break

    case 2:
        bomb3.position.y = frame.size.height

        let PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))

        bomb3.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

        self.addChild(bomb3)

        break

    case 3:
        bomb4.position.y = frame.size.height

        let PositionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))

        bomb4.position.x = CGFloat(PositionX)

        self.addChild(bomb4)

        break

    default:

        break

    }

   bomb1.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(airDefense.position, duration: 5))
   bomb2.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(airDefense.position, duration: 5))
   bomb3.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(airDefense.position, duration: 5))
   bomb4.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(airDefense.position, duration: 5))

}
```

This is what I am calling in touches Began to create the bombs

```
enemyTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("enemies"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: You don't show us the code for where the _"update function"_ is, but consider using inequality matching `bombCounter >= 10` rather than `... == 10` in situations such as the one above (no reason to use equality matching in this context). Equality matching is more complex both logically (unexpected: do we actually call this function for each new bomb or say for each new 4 bombs? `0, 4, 8, 12, ...` <-- no exact equality to 10) and due to the risk or imprecision (e.g. floating point comparison; not an issue here).

Comment: It's just some code from previous answers I've tried so I'm not even sure if it's in the right place. I agree with you though >= is better.

Comment: For us to help you out, you need to show us where you call the update function in your code, as it is now, it's a free-floating block of code of unknown origin. Anyway, from the above, it is possible that your update functions is called only after each quadruple of bomb (in which case the equality matching will fail, as # of bombs will never be 10). If this question is about _game design_ rather than programming, possibly you should try your luck at [http://gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) rather than SO.

Comment: I edited it to show the update func. I don't have any kind of func i made if thats what you were referring to. Thanks for your help!

Comment: as far as the bombs they are not dropped in groups of 4 they are dropped one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better approach is

1. Add a new var called `lastTimeAddedBomb`
2. Decide on your interval by tracking how much bombs you released
3. Check if you need to add a new bomb in your `update` method

Like this:

```
var lastTimeAddedBomb:NSDate
var numberOfBombsDropped:Int = 0
var difficultyLevel:Float = 1

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (numberOfBombsDropped % 10 == 0) {
        difficultyLevel-= 0.1;
    }

    let intervalForBombs = difficultyLevel

    let timeFromLastBomb = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(lastTimeAddedBomb)
    if (timeFromLastBomb >= intervalForBombs) {
        //call bomb
        //save last bomb date as now
        numberOfBombsDropped++
        lastTimeAddedBomb = NSDate()
    } 
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, even though: `I would like it to get harder every 10 bombs.`

Comment: Ok, instead tracking the time track the number of bombs you released and use that variable to determine the difficulty level.

Comment: @Godric I've updated the answer to reflect the solution.

Comment: Funny, I did add an answer 20 min ago. But nice to see another solution.

Comment: @Godric, I did not mean to take away any credit :), the original posted alerted me why I didn't answer his question correctly. So I fixed mine :)

Comment: Did he? Or was it me all the time? ;-)

Comment: @Godric You've deceived me! I was sure that's the original poster :)

Comment: Just now getting to try this, Thanks a lot for yalls help! lol btw I didn't alert anyone lol but it tried the above code and on this line... if (timeFromLastBomb >= intervalForBombs) {  its says Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'Double') and 'Float'

Comment: also it says my Class GameScene has no initializers?

Comment: Nvm fixed the no init,  I had to change var lastTimeAddedBomb:NSDate to var lastTimeAddedBomb = NSDate()

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not increment the bombCounter and it does reset the bombSpawnSpeed to 0.1 9 out of 10 updates.
The update method may be to often to reduce the bombSpawnSpeed. But if the rate is good you could use it.
If you do not increase the bombCounter elsewhere you could increase it in the update method.
A variable that knows the last time you dropped a bomb would be good too.

```
var lastDroppedBombTime: NSDate

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    bombCounter += 1
    if bombCounter >= 10 {
        bombSpawnSpeed -= 0.05
        bombCounter = 0
    }

    let differenceInTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(lastDroppedBombTime) // or use the difference of the parameter currentTime and lastDroppedBombTime
    if (differenceInTime >= bombSpawnSpeed) {
        enemies() // spawn the new bomb(s)
        lastDroppedBombTime = NSDate()
    }
}
```

Comment: where you say drop a bomb I'm using enemyTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("enemies"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
should this work?

Comment: @TimmySorensen if you want to drop a bomb, you simply create the bombs immediately, in your case you are creating the bombs in enemies(). Added your function name to reflect that.

Comment: thanks @Godric! how can I call this once touchesBegan? right now with it in the update method it starts loading bombs as soon as screen loads

Comment: never mind, i but i gameStarted Bool in the update func that seems to have it fixed :)